# Samba shares are accessible only for a specific user set by chown

Tags: linux, permissions, centos, samba, ownership

I've stumbled upon a peculiar issue regarding samba share.
It only works when ownership is given to the samba user (`shared`) by running `chown -R shared:sambasecure /mnt/Backup`. I'm running CentOS 8, SELinux enabled. Let me explain what I did.

I created a user (`shared`) and a group (`sambasecure`)

```
adduser --no-create-hom --shell /usr/sbin/nologin shared
smbpasswd -a shared
smbpasswd -e shared
usermod -G sambasecure shared
```

I set permissions (777 for testing purposes) and ownership

```
chown -R root:sambasecure /mnt/Backup
chcon -t samba_share_t /mnt/Backup
chmod 777 /mnt/Backup
```

My smb.conf

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    netbios name = server
    passdb backend = tdbsam
    interfaces = team0
    printing = cups
    printcap name = cups
    load printers = yes
    cups options = raw

[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    valid users = %S, %D%w%S
    browseable = No
    read only = No
    inherit acls = Yes
    
[media]
    path = /mnt/Backup
    writeable = yes
    write list = @sambasecure
    valid users = @sambasecure
    browseable = yes
    guest ok = no
```

Now, in this configuration file sharing does not work. Windows cannot access \... warning shows up.
But if I run `chown -R shared:sambasecure /mnt/Backup` sharing works but I cannot access drives locally.

chmod doesn't affect this at all. It either works for root locally or samba user `shared` over samba, just by changing ownership.

It seems to me like samba doesn't recognize `shared` to be a part of `sambasecure` group.
I tried many variations of smb.conf with zero success.
Changing valid users to `shared` doesn't work either.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Solved using `setfacl -m user:shared:rwx /mnt/MediaFiles/`. But I stiill don't get why it won't work with group sambasecure only.

Comment: I think the problem is related to the command `chown -R root:sambasecure`. This set the owner to root. It might be better to use `chown -R :sambasecure`.